# How to condense this jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I condense the following to one line so I can use it in my swift code when evaluatingJavascript?

```
let options = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#size-options > option"));

let large = options.filter(function(item){
  return item.textContent === "Large";
});

$("#size-options").val(large[0].value).change();
```

This is where I need to put the one line of code into:

```
self.TESTWKWebView.evaluateJavaScript("", completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Every JS code (if formatted properly and the `;` are placed where needed) can be a *"oneliner"*. In your case you might replace all `"` with `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `:contains()` and `:eq()` selectors to make a oneliner:

```js
$('#size-options').val($('#size-options option:contains(Large):eq(0)').val()).change()
```

But the `:eq()` is not even needed since `.val()` will by default give you the value of the first element in collection, therefore:

```js
$('#size-options').val($('#size-options option:contains(Large)').val()).change()
```

```html
<select id="size-options">
  <option value="s1">Small 1</option>
  <option value="s2">Small 2</option>
  <option value="l1">Large 1</option>
  <option value="l2">Large 2</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So I believe your evaluation could become:

```
self.TESTWKWebView.evaluateJavaScript("$('#size-options').val($('#size-options option:contains(Large):eq(0)').val()).change()", completionHandler: nil)
```

if it can digest jQuery code OFC, otherwise

#### Evaluating pure JS

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('#size-options option')].some(el => {
  if (/Large/.test(el.textContent)) {
    el.parentNode.value = el.value;
    el.parentNode.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="size-options">
  <option value="s1">Small 1</option>
  <option value="s2">Small 2</option>
  <option value="l1">Large 1</option>
  <option value="l2">Large 2</option>
</select>
```

Or in your case:

```
self.TESTWKWebView.evaluateJavaScript("[...document.querySelectorAll('#size-options option')].some(el => {if (/Large/.test(el.textContent)) {el.parentNode.value = el.value;el.parentNode.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));return true;}});", completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: How would I convert the $ to something like "document." cause I don't know if evaluateJavaScript allows $.

Comment: @Andrew added another example

Comment: The new code works but where do I put change(). That is all thats left! Sorry.

Comment: @Andrew does the third example helps?

Comment: The third example doesn't physically change the item. The code I posted changes it. I think dispatchEvent is differen't from change(). I am testing your code in console.

Comment: @Andrew would than `el.parentNode.onchange()` fit? I'm asking because `.change()` is jQuery's way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189732/discussion-between-roko-c-buljan-and-andrew).

Comment: It worked, I used my original code and it worked! Thanks!